# Php, is there an array to iterator converter?

Tags: php

its good that there is iterator to array http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php but is there anything to do it reversed?

Comment: from the page you linked `$iterator = new ArrayIterator($array)`

Comment: What do you mean by do it reversed?

Comment: @ChinLeung: o not convert iterator to array BUT convert array to iterator

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php maybe

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input and expected output via `print_r()` or `var_dump()`? I am 99% sure that PHP has some obscure function for this or if not then it is trivial via a `for()`/`foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if *reversed* means *just make an Iterator from a given Array*.

```
$array = array(
  'a' => 1,
  2 => new stdClass,
  3 => array('subArrayStuff'=>'value')
);

$iterator = new ArrayObject($array);

$arrayAgain = iterator_to_array($iterator);
```

Try it.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Please read also [Difference between ArrayIterator, ArrayObject and Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502719/difference-between-arrayiterator-arrayobject-and-array-in-php).

Comment: example works, and the question itself does not going so far that i would explain that too ;-) Question woulde be: What kind of `Traversable` do you want to use in the first place? ;)

Comment: I thing the `iterator_to_array` handles that `getIterator()` problem internally . So it would be fine :)

Comment: why not `new ArrayIterator($array)`?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php Here's an example of MyIterator that uses an array. You can change the constructor and pass there any array

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array();  

    public function __construct($data = array()) {
        $this->array = $data;
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A little cheeky copying the manual page, when a comment with a link would have achieved the same thing

Comment: I've made the changes. Otherwise I would left the link in the comment. But yeah, it's based on copying from manual